# Invalidate() method on onDraw in android

Tags: java, android, ondraw

I'm doing a project in android studio. I just want to do a flashing light point using `onDraw()` and `invalidate()` but something is wrong.

This is the first class

```
public class flashingPoint extends View {

    private ShapeDrawable mParteDibujable;

    public flashingPoint(Context context){

        super(context);

        final Handler bridge = new Handler();

        Thread time = new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                bridge.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                invalidate();

            }

        };
        time.start();

        }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mParteDibujable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        mParteDibujable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
        mParteDibujable.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 80);

        mParteDibujable.draw(canvas);
        //invalidate();

    }
```

And then the main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ShapeDrawable mParteDibujable;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        flashingPoint myView = new flashingpoint(this);
        mLinearLayout.addView(myView);

        setContentView(mLinearLayout);

    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `postInvalidateDelayed(time)`   see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidateDelayed(long))

Answer (score 3):

If you have the timer, you neither need nor want the invalidate in onDraw.  Invalidating in onDraw is both logically weird and will lead to poor results-  it would either be ignored, or it would cause an immediate redraw.  Neither is desired.

Also, you can't invalidate on a Thread, you'd need to use postInvalidate.  And your thread is wrong-  either don't use a thread, use a Runnable and post it to the Handler, or the thread should infinitely loop, not return.  Preferably the first, there's no reason to have a thread here at all.